# Convert to german date string in SQL Server 2008

Tags: string, datetime, sql-server-2008-r2, format, date-conversion

I'm using

```
DECLARE @testdate datetime = '2021-12-24 03:12:55PM'
SELECT FORMAT(@testdate, 'dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss', 'de-de')
```

Result is: 24 Dez 2021 15:12:55

In 2008 I can not use FORMAT(), so I'm using

```
DECLARE @testdate datetime = '2021-12-24 03:12:55PM'
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(20),@testdate,113)
```

Result ist: 24 Dec 2021 15:12:55

Any idea how to get german result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include a `SET LANGUAGE` command to make it return in German:

```
DECLARE @testdate datetime = '2021-12-24 03:12:55PM'
SET LANGUAGE 'German'
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(20),@testdate,113)
```

I set the first part outside the `SET LANGUAGE` statement as the date string needs to be properly parsed in German to do an implicit conversion and I didn't understand the error message in German it threw.